# Codeigniter MY_Model: cannot perform validation

Tags: php, rest, codeigniter-3, my-model-jami

I'm using the model in the below link.
https://github.com/jamierumbelow/codeigniter-base-model

How do you validate the data in put method.
I have tried as like below.
config/form_validation.php

```
$config = array(

   'create_put' => array(
   array( 'field' => 'emailid', 'label' => 'email_address', 'rules' => 'trim|required|valid_email' ),
   array( 'field' => 'lastname', 'label' => 'lastname', 'rules' => 'trim|required|min_length[8]|max_length[16]' ),
   array( 'field' => 'leadname', 'label' => 'first_name', 'rules' => 'trim|required|max_length[50]' ),
   array( 'field' => 'website', 'label' => 'last_name', 'rules' => 'trim|required|max_length[50]' ),
   array( 'field' => 'mobilenumber', 'label' => 'phone_number', 'rules' => 'trim|required|alpha_dash' )
  )
```

And in lead controller method

```
function create_put() {
        //$this->load_model();
        //var_dump($this->put()) ;
          $this->load->library('form_validation');
          $lead = remove_unknown_fields($this->put(),$this->form_validation->get_field_names('create_put'));
            //print_r($data ); die;
            $this->form_validation->set_data($lead) ;
          if ($this->form_validation->run('create_put') != false){
           $this->load->model('Model_lead');
           $lead_id = $this->Model_lead->insert($lead);
           if (!$lead_id) {
            $this->response(array('status'=>'failure','message'=>'An un-expected error occured while trying to insert student details'),REST_Controller::HTTP_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
           }
            else {
             $this->response(array('status'=> 'success','message'=>'Student data successfully inserted'));
            }
          }else {
            $this->response(array('status'=> 'failure','message'=>$this->form_validation->get_errors_as_array()), REST_Controller::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST);
          }
}
```

Validation always throws error. check below response.

```
{
  "status": "valid failure",
  "message": []
}
```

I don't know why validation is not performed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was I have chosen form-data in postman instead of x-www-form-urlencoded option in header. 
I found that there was an issue created in someone's repo in below link.

https://github.com/alexmarton/RControl/issues/1

This might be the problem there too.
Everything is working fine now after selecting x-www-form-urlencoded in header.

Comment: Rumbelow's MY_Model is not maintained few years now. I suggst you to switch ove to [Avenirer](https://github.com/avenirer/CodeIgniter-MY_Model)'s one that use Jamie's code as a base and is maintained more recently.